# How to remove an object from another object in django? - python

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a queryset that created by `Profile.objects.all()`. I want to print it in template except just one of its rows. How can I do it in template? or if it's not possible in template, how can I do it in view?

Comment: `Profile.objects.all()` is not an object, it's a `queryset`. Could you please be more specific of your issue/problem?

Comment: yeah you right, it's a queryset. I want to print all of it's rows except one of them. for example if there is 5 rows in database table, i take all of them by `Profile.objects.all()`, but I want to print rows 1 to 4 and I don't want to print rows number 5.

Comment: Profile.objects.all().exclude(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.exclude()` queryset like this :

```
YourObjet = Profile.objects.exclude(**kwargs)
```

This Django Query will return all objects in your Model without excluded objects.

You have django documentation there : [.exclude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/topics/db/queries/)

**Example :**

```
MyObject = Individu.objects.all()
```

**Return :**

`<QuerySet [<Individu: 1 19312STRASBOURG-402541 JUNGBLUTH Valentin>, <Individu: 2 18812STRASBOURG-797846 ARNOUD Laurent>, <Individu: 3 None TEST Test>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>`

```
MyObject = Individu.objects.exclude(id="2")
```

**Return :**

`<QuerySet [<Individu: 1 19312STRASBOURG-402541 JUNGBLUTH Valentin>, <Individu: 3 None TEST Test>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>`

Comment: isn't it possible to do it in template?

Comment: You juste have to add `YourObject` in the context dictionary in your view. Then call `YourObject` variable in your template and it works

Comment: I added an example ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all `Profile.objects.all()` is a `QuerySet`. You can print out the `__str__()` method of each instance in the `QuerySet` just by iterating through it.

If you only want to neglect the last one, you could something like this,

```
{% for item in profiles %}

    {% if not forloop.last %}

        {{ item }}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's not the better answer. Because it works for the last object but not object with ID=10 with 1.000.000 objects. You have to use `.exclude()` to do that.

Comment: True, when you have multiple objects with some common conditions which you donot want to show.